# No cell values error when cropping raster using crop from raster package R

Tags: raster, r, sf

I'm trying something very trivial - cropping a large raster to a smaller extent using a sf object. The raster is cropped with no errors but when I try and plot the cropped raster I get the following error:

```
Error in .plotraster2(x, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, add = add,  :
```

no values associated with this RasterLayer

Both the raster and sf object are in the same crs/projection.

I wonder if it has anything to do with the versions of raster/rgdal and the GDAL/PROJ libraries that these packages are compiled against?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, R version 3.6.3.

Here's my simple script:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)

sourceFile <- file.path('cigGhana_25.geojson')
gridGhana <- raster('gha_px_area_100m.tif')


# subset
shp <- st_read(sourceFile)
shp = shp[1,] # select on feature from the sf collection
grd <- raster(gridGhana)
grd <- crop(grd, extent(shp)) # crop grid to extent of the shp


plot(grd)
#Error in .plotraster2(x, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, add = add,  : 
#                        no values associated with this RasterLayer
```

And my source raster and vector files are here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1stmPsEOMek-1J5vJBPRcGyVLAIh1jgx9/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11-VKlOksQKdy_mafFg9UpoR2HIo47lqo/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loaded `gridGhana` with

```r
gridGhana <- raster('gha_px_area_100m.tif')
```

But when doing

```r
grd <- raster(gridGhana)
```

You actually created an empty raster using `gridGhana` as template. So `grd` is just empty, this is why it does not plot.

```r
library(sf)
library(raster)

shp <- st_read('cigGhana_25.geojson')
gridGhana <- raster('gha_px_area_100m.tif')

shp = shp[1,] # select on feature from the sf collection
grd <- crop(gridGhana, extent(shp)) # crop grid to extent of the shp

plot(grd)
```

Comment: thanks, silly me. Thanks that's just the ticket!